# Where to retrieve used API key in a HTTP request

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, api-key

I'm trying to develop an Endpoint for uploading files that is only accessible using an API key. I use the `Django REST Framework API Key` and my  code in `viewsets.py` is as follows:

```
class UploadFileViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = File
    queryset = File.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FileSerializer
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser] # not sure whether required
    permission_classes = [HasAPIKey]

       def create(self, request):
        serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data) # converts to JSON
        if serializer.is_valid(True):          # validating the data
            model_instance = serializer.save()  # saving the data into database
```

I'd like to be able to pick out various attributes from request, for example, its source (in this case the API Key). When I debug I can't find the API key in the request. Is it because it's actually not present in the request, but is already "eaten up" beforehand in Django's middleware? I'm a bit confused why I can't  retrieve it, and if I can actually get a source from the http request at all.